# Rails, initialize object with ID and keep it reserved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hally everybody, I'm trying to figure how to manage a situation like this.

I have a model

```
Class Content < Activerecord

 has_many                :elements
 has_many                :assets, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

I have a form, and of course in my controller I have

```
def new
 @content = Content.new
end
```

Let's take "assets".
Assets are files like js, css, and I'm using a jquery widget inside my form to upload them.

Elements are simile to form: I create them inside the "new form".

In the actual version of my app in my controller I use

```
def new
 @content = Content.create
end
```

I create and save on db every content so I have te ID, and I use the ID to upload the assets with the jquery widget and to create the pages using an ajax post.

Using "Content.new" I don't have any ID, I initialize my content model and I don't have any ID.

Is there any workaround? Is possible to initialize with an ID and reserve this ID to avoid override? Or I have to change my interface?

Comment: what does your `create` look like?

Answer (score 0):

If your Content will belongs_to some other Model, then you can create an object with some id!

```
Class Content < Activerecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many                :elements
 has_many                :assets, :dependent => :destroy

end

Class User < Activerecord
  has_many :contents
end

Content.create(user_id: 1)

will return
#<Content id: 10008, user_id: 1 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the empty content to create an empty record or reserve the record in your database.

```
def new
 @content = Content.create
 @content.save!
end
```

But beware that if you're reserving an id/record in the database, you'll need to destroy it if your form fails for some reason. Or live with empty records in case of failure.